# browser back button after logout in springboot

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

when click logout it will redirect to login page but when i click twice browser back button im getting redirected to dashboard . this happen when i click twice only
below is my securityconfig code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class  SecurityConfig{

    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
        httpSecurity
        .authorizeHttpRequests(auth->{
          auth.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                  .requestMatchers("/errorpage").permitAll()
                  .requestMatchers("/dashboard").permitAll()
                  .requestMatchers("/createadmin").permitAll()
                  .requestMatchers("/employee/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/module/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/designation/**").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/privilege").hasAnyAuthority("Admin")
                  .requestMatchers("/salesdrug").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/purchasedrug").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/category").hasAnyAuthority("Admin","Manager")
                  .requestMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()

                  .anyRequest().authenticated();
        })
          .formLogin(login->{
                  login.loginPage("/login")
                       .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard" , true)
                          .failureUrl("/login?error=usernamepassworderror")
                          .usernameParameter("username")
                          .passwordParameter("password");
          })
            .logout(logout->{
                    logout
                            .clearAuthentication(true) // Clear credentials
                            .invalidateHttpSession(true) // Invalidate session
                            .logoutUrl("/logout")
                            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");




            })
                .exceptionHandling(exception->{
                    exception.accessDeniedPage("/errorpage");
                })
                .csrf(csrf->{
                    csrf.disable();
                });
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        bCryptPasswordEncoder=new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

}
```

an this is my javascript code to get user confirmation

```
const logoutconfirm=()=>{
    Swal.fire({
        title: "Are you sure to logout",

        icon: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
        cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
        confirmButtonText: "Confirm"
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            // window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/logout";
            const form = document.createElement("form");
            form.method = "POST";
            form.action = "/logout";
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
        else{
            Swal.fire({
                icon: "error",
                title: "Action Aborted"


            });
        }
    });
}
```

what is the reason for that happening and i coudnt find a solution for this in internet